# How do I remove hours and seconds from my DataFrame column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame :

```
Age Gender Address     Date
15    M    172 ST   2022-02-07 00:00:00
```

I Want to remove hh:mm:ss
I tried:

```
import datetime as dt
df["Date"]=df["Date"].dt.Date .
```

But I am receiving no change in date column format.

All I want is that the date column has only (YYYY-MM-DD).

Comment: How about `df["Date"]=df["Date"].dt.date`?

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt work

Comment: What's the result of `df.dtypes`.

Comment: everything is an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` to convert `Date` column to datetime object.

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
# or
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# or
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.split(' ').str[0]
```